# Angular [selected] not working with formControlName

Tags: angular

I have the following basic setup:

In my component.ts:

```ts
const usersFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  ...
  defaultSeNumber: [''],
  ...
});

this.settingsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  usersForm: usersFormGroup,
  ...
});
```

And then I have the following HTML files:

Parent

```html
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    ...
    <child1 [formGroup]="formGroup.controls.usersForm"></child1>
    ...
</form>
```

Child1:

```html
<ng-container [formGroup]="formGroup">
    ...
    <child2 [selectedSeNumber]="'11012977'"></child2>
    ...
</ng-container>
```

Child2:

```html
<select class="form-select input-width-xl abc" id="seNumber">
<option *ngFor="let item of seNumbers;" [value]="item.seNumber"
        [selected]="item.seNumber == selectedSeNumber">{{ item.seNumber }}</option>
</select>
```

I cannot figure out how to carry the `formControlName` all the way down to the `<select>` so that both `[selected]` will work *and* the selected value will be carried back to my `settingsForm` upon form submit.

I have tried most combinations of `formControlName`/`[formControlName]` on every component.

I should add that I CAN get [selected] to work but then the value is not sent back onSubmit. Also I CAN get the value sent back onSubmit but then [selected] is not working.

I would like the child2 component to take necessary input to make it a reusable form component with a customizable formControlName.

Comment: I got the same issues a few months ago on my angular project. I made same thing like you. But, it did not work. My solution is that No Custom Component inside angular form because it will not work sometimes and fail on validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your typescript file inside `ngOnInit()` add`this.usersFormGroup.controls["defaultSeNumber"].setValue(this.selectedSeNumber);`

Remove `[selected]="item.seNumber == selectedSeNumber"`

Comment: This works with one exception: My formControlName will have to be the same always. This is something I can live with untill I have to put two child2 components into the same form.

Answer (score 1):

If you create the form in the main.app, why not pass the formControl or formGroup and use [formControl]="control" in children?

Parent

```
formGroup=new FormGroup({
   ...
   usersForm:new FormGroup({
      ....
      selectedSeNumber:new FormControl()
   })
})

<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    ...
    <child1 [group]="formGroup.get('usersForm')"></child1>
    ...
</form>
```

Child 1

```
@Input('group')fromGroup:FormGroup

<ng-container [formGroup]="formGroup">
    ...
    <child2 [control]="formGroup.get('selectedSeNumber')"></child2>
    ...
</ng-container>
```

Child2

```
@Input('control') formControl:FormControl

<select class="form-select input-width-xl abc" id="seNumber" 
    [formControl]="formControl">
    <option *ngFor="let item of seNumbers;" [value]="item.seNumber">
       {{ item.seNumber }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: That's also sort of what I did. May main formGroup consists of 4 individual fromGroups, eached passed to a component and passed on to further subcomponents.